# Unable to complete payment in paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I have an issue with making PayPal sandbox payments. Whenever I try to make a payment it requires me to log into the buyer account, but when I do log in I get redirected to the buyer profile page. If I then try to repeat the payment again, it still asks me to log in and if I do login I once again get redirected to the buyer profile page.
The payments were working fine a day or two ago on a test server that hasn't had anything changed on it since then. I tried clearing cookies and going incognito as recommended by some people, but that didn't seem to help.
Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to myself it seems that it's a problem with PayPal sandbox which is broken and nobody cares about it at PayPal!!! I waste 3 days on this problem. Grrrr

I also found this: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business/Paypal-redirect-issue/m-p/1242652

AND this: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments/Something-change-with-paypal-sandbox-donations/m-p/1246095#M97864

I am seriously looking for an alternative to PayPal to manage my subscriptions buttons. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Best Regards,

HB

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same issue with a subscription button... What's going on with PayPal?

My code is as follows:

```
<form action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' target='_top'>
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='example-facilitator@example.com' />
<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick-subscriptions' />
<input type='hidden' name='country' value='UK' />
<input type='hidden' name='no_note' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='charset' value='utf-8' />
<input type='hidden' name='lc' value='UK' />
<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='sra' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='src' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='modify' value='0' />
<input type='hidden' name='usr_manage' value='0' />
<input type='hidden' name='invoice' value='INV-L1-2000002-1498316504' />
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='pln-l1s0p0' />
<input type='hidden' name='p3' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='t3' value='M' />
<input type='hidden' name='rm' value='0' />
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.example.com' />
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://www.example.com' />
<input type='hidden' name='shopping_url' value='http://www.example.com' />
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Monthly subscription: Basic Plan' id='item_name-basic-monthly' />
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='GBP' />
<select name='a3' id='a3-basic-monthly' style='font-size:110%;'>
<option value='5.00'>5.00 GBP (no options)</option>
<option value='9.80'>+ Options: 9.80 GBP</option>
</select>
<input style='width:170px; height:40px;' type='image' src='https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif' border='0' name='submit' alt='Purchase with PayPal' />
<img alt='' border='0' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif' width='1' height='1' />
</form>
```

Best Regards,

HB